# Android Studio gradle sync read timeout

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies

I'm trying to import Aliyun's httpdns package in my project. But when trying to sync project with it as a dependency, every time the sync failed because the download always timeout, however, I tried to download it directly in a browser, via terminal. I even tried with the Android Studio proxy -> check connection. It showed the connection was ok.

The url of the dependency is 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/aliyun/ams/alicloud-android-httpdns/1.1.3/alicloud-android-httpdns-1.1.3.pom'

This is my project build.gradle file, set up according to the document.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/'
    }
}
```

}

And this is what I get every time I try to sync project.

```
org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/aliyun/ams/alicloud-android-httpdns/1.1.3/alicloud-android-httpdns-1.1.3.pom'.
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved by replacing the sock5 proxy to http proxy.

Really should dig a bit deeper into shadowsocks living in China....

Comment: Sadly, I have not solved for a week in China. Can you share shadowsocks account for me for just one time?

Comment: I am also getting the same exception, I am stck here for 4 days.Please help me on this.My Question --  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60182192/updated-androidstudio3-5-3-not-building-android-project-caused-by-org-gradle?noredirect=1#comment106492346_60182192